# jQuery bootstrap script seem to be conflicting with another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a customized version of twitter bootstrap along with another script (ACT Theme) for the mobile navigation. But for some reason when I add both of them, they seem to be conflicting with each other.

To be specific, after clicking on the tabs thrice, or after clicking the Bootstrap carousel arrow thrice, it is no longer functional. But if I remove the ACT script, the functionality is normal.

Added the script to JSFiddle.net since it is slightly larger than what is allowed here.

Here is the customized bootstrap script along with the ACT theme script:

https://jsfiddle.net/2uhaf07L/

```
 /*!
     * Act Theme - JavaScript v1.2.10
     * (c) Copyright Neambo (www.neambo.com)
     * Unminified version: contact@neambo.com
     */
    "use strict";/*!
     * FitVids 1.1
     * Copyright 2013, Chris Coyier - http://css-tricks.com + Dave Rupert - http://daverupert.com
     * Credit to Thierry Koblentz - http://www.alistapart.com/articles/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/
     * Released under the WTFPL license - http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/
     */
    !function(t){t.fn.fitVids=function(e){var i={customSelector:null,ignore:null};if(!document.getElementById("fit-vids-style")){var n=document.head||document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],o=".fluid-width-video-wrapper{width:100%;position:relative;padding:0;}.fluid-width-video-wrapper iframe,.fluid-width-video-wrapper object,.fluid-width-video-wrapper embed {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;}",s=document.createElement("div");s.innerHTML='<p>x</p><style id="fit-vids-style">'+o+"</style>",n.appendChild(s.childNodes[1])}return e&&t.extend(i,e),this.each(function(){var e=["iframe[src*='player.vimeo.com']","iframe[src*='youtube.com']","iframe[src*='youtube-nocookie.com']","iframe[src*='kickstarter.com'][src*='video.html']","object","embed"];i.customSelector&&e.push(i.customSelector);var n=".fitvidsignore";i.ignore&&(n=n+", "+i.ignore);var o=t(this).find(e.join(","));o=o.not("object object"),o=o.not(n),o.each(function(){var e=t(this);if(!(e.parents(n).length>0||"embed"===this.tagName.toLowerCase()&&e.parent("object").length||e.parent(".fluid-width-video-wrapper").length)){e.css("height")||e.css("width")||!isNaN(e.attr("height"))&&!isNaN(e.attr("width"))||(e.attr("height",9),e.attr("width",16));var i="object"===this.tagName.toLowerCase()||e.attr("height")&&!isNaN(parseInt(e.attr("height"),10))?parseInt(e.attr("height"),10):e.height(),o=isNaN(parseInt(e.attr("width"),10))?e.width():parseInt(e.attr("width"),10),s=i/o;if(!e.attr("id")){var r="fitvid"+Math.floor(999999*Math.random());e.attr("id",r)}e.wrap('<div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper"></div>').parent(".fluid-width-video-wrapper").css("padding-top",100*s+"%"),e.removeAttr("height").removeAttr("width")}})})}}(window.jQuery||window.Zepto),/*!



    * Handle lack of OBJECT.BIND() in old IE
     */
    Function.prototype.bind||(Function.prototype.bind=function(t){if("function"!=typeof this)throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1),i=this,n=function(){},o=function(){return i.apply(this instanceof n&&t?this:t,e.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)))};return n.prototype=this.prototype,o.prototype=new n,o}),!function(t,e){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],e):e("object"==typeof exports?require("jquery"):t.jQuery)}(this,function(t){function e(t){var e,i,n,o,s,r,a,c={};for(s=t.replace(/\s*:\s*/g,":").replace(/\s*,\s*/g,",").split(","),a=0,r=s.length;r>a&&(i=s[a],-1===i.search(/^(http|https|ftp):\/\//)&&-1!==i.search(":"));a++)e=i.indexOf(":"),n=i.substring(0,e),o=i.substring(e+1),o||(o=void 0),"string"==typeof o&&(o="true"===o||"false"!==o&&o),"string"==typeof o&&(o=isNaN(o)?o:+o),c[n]=o;return null==n&&null==o?t:c}function i(t){t=""+t;var e,i,n,o=t.split(/\s+/),s="50%",r="50%";for(n=0,e=o.length;e>n;n++)i=o[n],"left"===i?s="0%":"right"===i?s="100%":"top"===i?r="0%":"bottom"===i?r="100%":"center"===i?0===n?s="50%":r="50%":0===n?s=i:r=i;return{x:s,y:r}}function n(e,i){var n=function(){i(this.src)};t('<img src="'+e+'.gif">').load(n),t('<img src="'+e+'.jpg">').load(n),t('<img src="'+e+'.jpeg">').load(n),t('<img src="'+e+'.png">').load(n)}function o(i,n,o){if(this.$element=t(i),"string"==typeof n&&(n=e(n)),o?"string"==typeof o&&(o=e(o)):o={},"string"==typeof n)n=n.replace(/\.\w*$/,"");else if("object"==typeof n)for(var s in n)n.hasOwnProperty(s)&&(n[s]=n[s].replace(/\.\w*$/,""));this.settings=t.extend({},r,o),this.path=n;try{this.init()}catch(t){if(t.message!==a)throw t}}var s="vide",r={volume:1,playbackRate:1,muted:!0,loop:!0,autoplay:!0,position:"50% 50%",posterType:"detect",resizing:!0,bgColor:"transparent"},a="Not implemented";o.prototype.init=function(){var e,o,r=this,c=r.path,u=c,h="",l=r.$element,d=r.settings,p=i(d.position),f=d.posterType;o=r.$wrapper=t("<div>").css({position:"absolute","z-index":-1,top:0,left:0,bottom:0,right:0,overflow:"hidden","-webkit-background-size":"cover","-moz-background-size":"cover","-o-background-size":"cover","background-size":"cover","background-color":d.bgColor,"background-repeat":"no-repeat","background-position":p.x+" "+p.y}),"object"==typeof c&&(c.poster?u=c.poster:c.mp4?u=c.mp4:c.webm?u=c.webm:c.ogv&&(u=c.ogv)),"detect"===f?n(u,function(t){o.css("background-image","url("+t+")")}):"none"!==f&&o.css("background-image","url("+u+"."+f+")"),"static"===l.css("position")&&l.css("position","relative"),l.prepend(o),"object"==typeof c?(c.mp4&&(h+='<source src="'+c.mp4+'.mp4" type="video/mp4">'),c.webm&&(h+='<source src="'+c.webm+'.webm" type="video/webm">'),c.ogv&&(h+='<source src="'+c.ogv+'.ogv" type="video/ogg">'),e=r.$video=t("<video>"+h+"</video>")):e=r.$video=t('<video><source src="'+c+'.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="'+c+'.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="'+c+'.ogv" type="video/ogg"></video>');try{e.prop({autoplay:d.autoplay,loop:d.loop,volume:d.volume,muted:d.muted,defaultMuted:d.muted,playbackRate:d.playbackRate,defaultPlaybackRate:d.playbackRate})}catch(t){throw new Error(a)}e.css({margin:"auto",position:"absolute","z-index":-1,top:p.y,left:p.x,"-webkit-transform":"translate(-"+p.x+", -"+p.y+")","-ms-transform":"translate(-"+p.x+", -"+p.y+")","-moz-transform":"translate(-"+p.x+", -"+p.y+")",transform:"translate(-"+p.x+", -"+p.y+")",visibility:"hidden",opacity:0}).one("canplaythrough."+s,function(){r.resize()}).one("playing."+s,function(){e.css({visibility:"visible",opacity:1}),o.css("background-image","none")}),l.on("resize."+s,function(){d.resizing&&r.resize()}),o.append(e)},o.prototype.getVideoObject=function(){return this.$video[0]},o.prototype.resize=function(){if(this.$video){var t=this.$wrapper,e=this.$video,i=e[0],n=i.videoHeight,o=i.videoWidth,s=t.height(),r=t.width();r/o>s/n?e.css({width:r+2,height:"auto"}):e.css({width:"auto",height:s+2})}},o.prototype.destroy=function(){delete t[s].lookup[this.index],this.$video&&this.$video.off(s),this.$element.off(s).removeData(s),this.$wrapper.remove()},t[s]={lookup:[]},t.fn[s]=function(e,i){var n;return this.each(function(){n=t.data(this,s),n&&n.destroy(),n=new o(this,e,i),n.index=t[s].lookup.push(n)-1,t.data(this,s,n)}),this},t(document).ready(function(){var e=t(window);e.on("resize."+s,function(){for(var e,i=t[s].lookup.length,n=0;i>n;n++)e=t[s].lookup[n],e&&e.settings.resizing&&e.resize()}),e.on("unload."+s,function(){return!1}),t(document).find("[data-"+s+"-bg]").each(function(e,i){var n=t(i),o=n.data(s+"-options"),r=n.data(s+"-bg");n[s](r,o)})})});var act={};act.debounce=function(t,e){var i=null;return function(){var n=this,o=arguments;clearTimeout(i),i=setTimeout(function(){t.apply(n,o)},e)}},act.throttle=function(t,e,i){e||(e=250);var n,o;return function(){var s=i||this,r=+new Date,a=arguments;n&&r<n+e?(clearTimeout(o),o=setTimeout(function(){n=r,t.apply(s,a)},e)):(n=r,t.apply(s,a))}},jQuery(function(t){function e(e,i){var n=0;e.css("min-height",e.outerHeight()),i.addClass("notransition").css("min-height","").each(function(){var e=t(this).outerHeight();e>n&&(n=e)}).css("min-height",n).delay(100).queue(function(){t(this).removeClass("notransition").dequeue()}),e.css("min-height","")}function i(){t(".act-slider .hs_cos_flex-slider .superimpose .caption").wrapInner('<div class="centered" />'),t(".act-slider .hs_cos_flex-slider .superimpose .caption p, .act-slider .hs_cos_flex-slider .superimpose .caption h1, .act-slider .hs_cos_flex-slider .superimpose .caption h2, .act-slider .hs_cos_flex-slider .superimpose .caption h3, .act-slider .hs_cos_flex-slider .superimpose .caption h4, .act-slider .hs_cos_flex-slider .superimpose .caption h5, .act-slider .hs_cos_flex-slider .superimpose .caption h6, .act-slider .hs_cos_flex-slider .superimpose .caption blockquote, .act-slider .hs_cos_flex-slider .superimpose .caption q, .act-slider .hs_cos_flex-slider .superimpose .caption code, .act-slider .hs_cos_flex-slider .superimpose .caption pre, .act-slider .hs_cos_flex-slider .superimpose .caption cite").after('<span class="separate-inline-blocks" />')}function n(){var t=s.scrollTop();u.length>0&&(t>d?m.addClass("active"):m.removeClass("active")),g.length>0&&(t>95?g.addClass("active"):g.removeClass("active"))}function o(){a.hasClass("hs-inline-edit")||c.hasClass("inpage-editing")||0==y.length||y.each(function(){t(this).masonry({isInitLayout:!1,transitionDuration:0});var e=t(this).data("masonry");e.on("layoutComplete",function(){a.addClass("flexible-listing-complete")}),e.layout()})}var s=t(window),r=t("html, body"),a=t("html"),c=t("body");a.removeClass("no-js").addClass("js-on"),t('[class*="span"]:not(.large-stack,.medium-stack,.small-stack,.tiny-stack,.never-stack)').addClass("smedium-stack"),t(".lt-ie9 .form-title, .lt-ie9 .page-header.section-header h1:empty, .lt-ie9 .page-header.section-header .section-subheader:empty").addClass("empty"),t(".lt-ie9 .hs-menu-wrapper li:last-child").addClass("last-child"),c.fitVids(),t(".fluid-width-video-wrapper").parent(".hs-responsive-embed").removeClass("hs-responsive-embed hs-responsive-embed-youtube hs-responsive-embed-vimeo"),t(".column-equal-height > div > div").each(function(){var i=t(this),n=i.find('> [class*="span"]:not(.span12)');e(i,n),s.on("load resize",act.throttle(function(){e(i,n)},250)),i.on("DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved",act.debounce(function(){e(i,n)},500)),t("*",n).on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd animationend webkitAnimationEnd",act.debounce(function(){e(i,n)},250))}),t(".header-wrapper.with-navigation .header-logo").append('<span class="mobile-menu-button"><i class="mobile-menu-button-line-top"></i><i class="mobile-menu-button-line-middle"></i><i class="mobile-menu-button-line-bottom"></i><span>'),t(".header-wrapper .main-navigation li.hs-item-has-children").append(function(){return t(this).find("ul").length>0?'<span class="mobile-menu-expand-button"></span>':void t(this).removeClass("hs-item-has-children")}),t(".mobile-menu-button").on("click",function(){t(this).toggleClass("expanded"),c.toggleClass("menu-is-open"),t(".header-wrapper .main-navigation .hs-menu-flow-horizontal").toggleClass("expanded"),t(".header-wrapper .main-navigation ul ul").hide(),t(".header-wrapper .main-navigation li.expanded").removeClass("expanded")}),t(".mobile-menu-expand-button").on("click",function(){var e=t(this).parent();e.parent("ul").parent("li");e.hasClass("expanded")?(e.removeClass("expanded").find("ul").hide().find(".expanded").removeClass("expanded"),e.siblings().removeClass("expanded").find("ul").hide().find("li.expanded").removeClass("expanded")):(e.addClass("expanded").find("> ul").show(),e.siblings().removeClass("expanded").find("ul").hide())}),t(".main-navigation ul li a > div").closest("li").addClass("extra-wrapper-primary"),t(".main-navigation ul li a > span").closest("li").addClass("extra-wrapper-secondary");var u=t(".header-wrapper .main-navigation.sticky");if(u.length>0){var h=t(".header-wrapper"),l=u.html(),d=h.height()+h.offset().top+100,p=u.attr("class").split(" "),f="sticky-menu menu-reset main-navigation";t.inArray("flyouts-fade",p)>-1&&(f+=" flyouts-fade"),t.inArray("flyouts-slide",p)>-1&&(f+=" flyouts-slide"),t.inArray("flyouts-flow-left-all",p)>-1&&(f+=" flyouts-flow-left-all"),t.inArray("flyouts-flow-left-last",p)>-1&&(f+=" flyouts-flow-left-last"),t.inArray("flyouts-flow-left-last-two",p)>-1&&(f+=" flyouts-flow-left-last-two"),t.inArray("flyouts-flow-left-last-three",p)>-1&&(f+=" flyouts-flow-left-last-three"),c.append('<div class="'+f+'"><div class="centered">'+l+'</div></div><div class="sticky-menu-option-check"></div>');var m=t(".sticky-menu")}0==t(".sub-menu li").length&&t(".sub-menu").addClass("empty"),t("html.lt-ie9").length>0?lookupInterval=setInterval(function(){t(".act-slider .hs_cos_flex-slider .superimpose .caption").length>0&&(clearInterval(lookupInterval),i())},100):s.on("load",i()),t(".act-slider .hs_cos_gallery_main .caption.superimpose > span").addClass("centered"),t(".act-slider .hs_cos_gallery_main .caption.superimpose p, .act-slider .hs_cos_gallery_main .caption.superimpose h1, .act-slider .hs_cos_gallery_main .caption.superimpose h2, .act-slider .hs_cos_gallery_main .caption.superimpose h3, .act-slider .hs_cos_gallery_main .caption.superimpose h4, .act-slider .hs_cos_gallery_main .caption.superimpose h5, .act-slider .hs_cos_gallery_main .caption.superimpose h6, .act-slider .hs_cos_gallery_main .caption.superimpose blockquote, .act-slider .hs_cos_gallery_main .caption.superimpose q, .act-slider .hs_cos_gallery_main .caption.superimpose code, .act-slider .hs_cos_gallery_main .caption.superimpose pre, .act-slider .hs_cos_gallery_main .caption.superimpose cite").after('<span class="separate-inline-blocks" />'),s.on("load",function(){t(".footer-subscribe .hs-input").on("focus",function(){t(".footer-go-foggy").foggy({blurRadius:2,opacity:.8,cssFilterSupport:!0})}),t(".footer-subscribe .hs-input").on("blur",function(){t(".footer-go-foggy").foggy(!1)})}),t(".map-section").append('<div class="map-overlay" />'),t(".map-overlay").on("click",function(){t(this).css("pointer-events","none")}),t(".next-section").prepend('<a class="next-section-arrow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>'),t(".next-section-arrow").on("click",function(){var e=t(this).closest(".next-section").offset().top;return r.animate({scrollTop:e},300,"easeOutExpo"),!1}),t(".lp-headlines-section").prepend('<a href="#" class="lp-arrow"></a>'),t(".lp-headlines-section .lp-arrow").on("click",function(){var e=t(".lp-arrow-target");return e.length>0&&r.animate({scrollTop:t(".lp-arrow-target").offset().top},300,"easeOutExpo"),!1}),c.prepend('<a name="top"></a>'),c.append('<span class="scroll-to-top"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></span>');var g=t(".scroll-to-top");g.on("click",function(){r.animate({scrollTop:0},300,"easeOutExpo")}),0==t("html.lt-ie9").length&&t("a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#], .popup-link)").on("click",function(){if(location.pathname.replace(/^\//,"")==this.pathname.replace(/^\//,"")&&location.hostname==this.hostname){var e=t(this.hash);if(e=e.length?e:t('[name="'+this.hash.slice(1)+'"]'),e.length){var i=e.offset().top;return t(".sticky-menu").length>0&&t(".sticky-menu-option-check").is(":visible")&&i>=55&&(i-=55),"top"==e.attr("name")&&(i=0),r.animate({scrollTop:i},300,"easeOutExpo"),!1}}}),"ie"===layoutEngine.vendor&&layoutEngine.version>=10&&"fixed"==t(".hero-wrapper, .hero-offer, .bottom-offer").css("background-attachment")&&c.on("mousewheel",function(){event.preventDefault?event.preventDefault():event.returnValue=!1;var t=event.wheelDelta,e=window.pageYOffset;window.scrollTo(0,e-t)});var v=/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g.test(navigator.userAgent);v&&c.append("<style>.hero-wrapper, .bottom-offer, .hero-offer { background-attachment: scroll !important; }</style>"),n(),s.on("scroll",function(){window.requestAnimationFrame(n)});var y=t(".flexible-listing:not(.no-masonry) > .hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container");if(t(window).on("load",function(){o(),c.hasClass("has-config-tool")&&(t('.nbo-config-select-styles, .slider-range, select[data-var-name="layout"], select[data-var-name="boxed_content_padding"]').on("change",function(){o()}),t(".nbo-config-reset").on("click",function(){o()}))}),t(window).smartresize(function(){window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){o()})}),t(".act-accordion-header").on("click",function(){var e=t(this).closest(".act-accordion-item"),i=e.attr("data-accordion-group");if(e.toggleClass("collapsed"),""!=i){var n=t('.act-accordion-item[data-accordion-group="'+i+'"]');n.not(t(this).closest(".act-accordion-item")).addClass("collapsed")}}),window.location.hash){var b=window.location.hash.replace(/^.*?(#|$)/,"").toLowerCase(),w=t("body").find('.act-accordion-item[data-accordion-anchor="'+b+'"]').first();w.length>0&&(w.removeClass("collapsed"),t('.act-accordion-item[data-accordion-group="'+w.attr("data-accordion-group")+'"]').not(w.closest(".act-accordion-item")).addClass("collapsed"),r.animate({scrollTop:w.offset().top-100},300,"easeOutExpo"))}t(".act-more-button-expand").on("click",function(){return t(this).closest(".act-more").removeClass("collapsed"),!1}),t(".act-more-button-collapse").on("click",function(){var e=t(this).closest(".act-more"),i=e.offset().top;return e.addClass("collapsed"),r.animate({scrollTop:i-100},300,"easeOutExpo"),!1}),t(".section-background-image img").each(function(){var e=t(this).attr("src");t(this).closest(".content-section").css("background-image","url("+e+")").addClass("background-image-defined")}),t(".section-background-color").each(function(){var e=t(this).find(".hs_cos_wrapper").text();t(this).closest(".content-section, .article-section").css("background-color",e).addClass("background-color-defined")}),t(".section-text-color").each(function(){var e=t(this).find(".hs_cos_wrapper").text();t(this).closest(".content-section").css("color",e).addClass("color-defined")});var _=t(".fullscreen-search"),x=_.find(".hs-input"),E=t(".main-navigation .hs-menu-wrapper > ul"),I='<a class="fss-open-btn" href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>';_.length>0&&E.length>0&&(a.addClass("fss-on"),_.find("form").before('<div class="fss-overlay"/>'),_.find(".hs-form label").length>0&&x.attr("placeholder",_.find(".hs-form label").text()),_.find(".hs-form label").remove(),_.find(".hs-button").html('<i class="fa fa-search"></i>'),E.append('<li class="menu-search-button">'+I+"</li>"),t(".mobile-menu-button").before('<div class="mobile-menu-search">'+I+"</div>"),_.hasClass("with-close")&&_.append('<a class="fss-close-btn" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>'),t(".fss-open-btn").on("click",function(){return a.addClass("fullscreen-search-open"),/iPad|iPhone|iPod/g.test(navigator.userAgent)||setTimeout(function(){x.focus()},250),!1}),t(".fss-close-btn").on("click",function(){return a.removeClass("fullscreen-search-open"),!1}),t(".fullscreen-search:not(.with-close.only-close)").find(".fss-overlay").on("click",function(){a.removeClass("fullscreen-search-open")}));var C=t(".hero-wrapper"),k={};if(C.find(".video-url").each(function(){var e=t(this).text().trim(),i=e.split(".").pop();i&&(k[i]=e)}),k.mp4){C.addClass("video-bg");var z={position:C.css("background-position"),bgColor:"transparent",posterType:"none"};C.vide(k,z)}t(".rss-cards").each(function(){t(".hs-rss-item",this).addClass("card-box").wrap('<div class="rss-card" />'),t(this).hasClass("full-links")&&t(".hs-rss-item").append(function(){return'<a  class="full-link" href="'+t(".hs-rss-description a",this).attr("href")+'" />'}),t(".hs-rss-description a",this).before('<span class="sep" />'),t("img.hs-rss-featured-image",this).each(function(){var e=t(this).closest(".hs-rss-item"),i=t(".hs-rss-description a",e).attr("href");e.addClass("has-image"),t(this).prependTo(e).wrap('<a href="'+i+'" class="rss-item-banner" />')})});var O=t(".rss-cards:not(.no-masonry) .hs-rss-module").masonry({itemSelector:".rss-card",isFitWidth:!0});O.imagesLoaded().progress(function(){O.masonry("layout")}),c.hasClass("has-config-tool")&&(t('.nbo-config-select-styles, .slider-range, select[data-var-name="layout"], select[data-var-name="boxed_content_padding"]').on("change",function(){O.masonry("layout")}),t(".nbo-config-reset").on("click",function(){O.masonry("layout")})),s.on("load resize",function(){O.masonry("layout")})});
```

Comment: Please make a working snippet reproducing your issue. How can we solve the problem if we cannot see it  ? just sharing a mile long script won't do any good :)

Comment: please provide to us a MCVE example for us, you have to test every script in your page to find the conflict.

Comment: Before asking a question, you need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means, _'Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem'_, _'Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem'_ and _'Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem'_